Footnote backreference and thanks (author and title) in maketitle
I want to have back references for footnotes. Utilizing package footnotebackref and hyperref works well for the whole document, but not for the thanks in author and title. Please advise me a solution. Many thanks.
A MWE follows.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\begin{document}

\title{My Title\footnote{Thank for support}}
\author{Name1\thanks{Position 1} \qquad\qquad Name2\thanks{Position 2}}

\maketitle

Text\footnote{The first footnote.} Text\\

Text\footnote[4]{The second footnote.} Text\\

Text\footnote{The third footnote.} Text

\end{document}

